# How get return request curl and paste it in a URL?

Tags: php, ajax, curl, telegram, urlencode

I have `file-A.php` where end in this way:

```
$testo= "L'abbonamento scade il: 25-08-2020 11:32 UTC";
print_r($testo);
return $testo;
```

then i have `file-B.php` where i have a function with `curl` for `file-A.php`
This function is:

```
function file_curl(){
 $url_file= "https://file-A.php";

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_file);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 $result= curl_exec($ch);   //esegui la chiamata
 curl_close($ch);

 $url= 'https://api.telegram.org/botxxx/sendMessage?chat_id=xxx&parse_mode=HTML&text='.$result; 
 file_get_contents($url);   
 return $result;
}
```

that `$url` and `file_get_contents`paste inside Telegram the `$result` but i don't know why output is only

```
L
```

Why ?

Comment: why send a post? Also, $query isn't defined. Also, url encode your string! Also, you can literally just echo the string, no need for print_r or return

Comment: That single quote cut off your codes L'abbonamento I think

Comment: @delboy1978uk i edited my post and i removed that string about $query (is not that the problem sure)

Comment: change that 1st file to just `echo urlencode("L'abbonamento scade il: 25-08-2020 11:32 UTC");`

Comment: @delboy1978uk done but nothing

Comment: @Dlk is impossible...

Comment: what is $result now?

Comment: Incidentally, where is your domain???? `https://file-A.php`

Comment: @delboy1978uk domain is not the problem anyway the $result is the same

Comment: what happ[ens when you browse to that script directly?